# Can't free() value allocated by malloc() in another function

Tags: c, memory-management, buffer-overflow

I have a C function, something like this:

```
void foo(char ** out) {
     *out = malloc(computedsize);
     if(*out != NULL){
         sprintf(*out, "%s,%s", foovar, baa);
      }
}
```

and then I call:

```
int main(void) {
   char * out = NULL;
   foo(&out);
   printf("%s\n", out); /* so far, it works fine */
   free(out); /* the problem. */ 
}
```

When I call:

`free(out);`

it given:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x09a03050 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6b161)[0x4ff161]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6c9b8)[0x5009b8]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0x503a9d]
./a.out[0x804875b]
./a.out[0x804871a]
./a.out[0x80486f9]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0x4aabd6]
./a.out[0x8048601]
======= Memory map: ========
```

//do need copy memory map part?

Can someone point out my mistake? I believe that's `sprintf()` call.. or no, actually, I have no idea. I tried too make a new variable inside function alloc value for it, and then `*out = myvariable;` and `*out = strdup(myvariable)` but the `free()` call give same error.

### Update

I see that the problem is inside the function. Any `free()` call inside it,causes the invalid next size.

for example:

```
char *f=malloc(2);
strcpy(f,"a");
free(f);
```

Inside `foo()` function, gets the above error, on `main()` function, works normally. I'm completely lost how to fix this.

Comment: You are trying to print your function as a string? How exactly is that supposed to work?

Comment: computedsize is probably too small, and you are overwriting past the end of the allocated space.

Comment: Try using [snprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) which is safer than sprintf.

Comment: @FatalError: Sorry. Was typo. I fixed.

Comment: What are the contents of foo and baa?

Comment: @Mahesh: "Safer"? How is it safer? `snprintf` simply replaces the "memory overrun" failure with "incomplete data" failure. While one might argue that the latter failure is "safer" than the former, I personally see very little point in comparing failures. "Safer" is when there's *no failure at all*.

Comment: @0x69: `-fstack-protector-all` watches for *stack* buffer overflows, as the name suggests. It won't help with dynamically allocated buffer overflows. Moreover, the diagnostic reported in the OP is actually the result of dynamic memory overrun protector *already* doing its work.

Comment: @AndreyT Well, using `snprintf` OP can prevent overrunning the buffer. If replacing with `snprintf` and the program runs fine, then OP can conclude that buffer overflow is the issue. That was my intention in the comment. And I agree your comment is completely acceptable.

Comment: @WilliamPursell:I have tried put a value like 256,but I get same error. the computed size value is something like: `strlen(foovar) + strlen(baa) + 2;` +2 because one for `,` and one for `\0`.

Comment: @SangeethSaravanaraj: two strings with 7 or 8 characters each.

Comment: @Jack: Can you edit your post to include a **complete** test-case (i.e. a complete piece of code that we compile and run)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

The problem actually,was on previous `malloc()`.An if() declaration call another function that do too a `malloc()`,but an `if()` inside called function,was not working as expected and cosequently storing some invalid values. This caused the heap corruption.

Answer (score 5):

You have probably written beyond the bounds of the allocated array, thus corrupting the heap (which contains metadata which `malloc`/`free` use to manage things).

Tools like Valgrind are designed to help you find this sort of error.

Comment: Thanks alot. I have now a direction to follow. I have tried valgrind sometime ago,but it doesn't works for me on any situation,the application simply crash.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, but I didn't have computedsize foo, or baa. I agree that you've probably written beyond the end of the memory you allocated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define COMPUTEDSIZE 1024
void foo(char ** out) {
     *out = malloc(COMPUTEDSIZE);
     if(*out != NULL){
         sprintf(*out, "%s,%s", "foo", "baa");
      }
}
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
   char * out = NULL;
   foo(&out);
   printf("%s\n", out); /* so far, it works fine */
   free(out); /* the problem. */ 
   exit(0);
}
```